Stripe payment issues and incomplete payment somehow being stored to db
The payment gateway is working fine and all, but sometimes even if I get the message that payment was successful, there's no entry in my db. I check the webhook screen and there are bunch of incomplete payments. When I come to check my db later on, I see bunch of payment entries in the db even when I am not using it, which I am guessing is because I go back from the payment screen? Even if payment is successful and it gets inserted in db, I am seeing two entries in the db at the same time. What is the problem here?
//Payment page
const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY as string)

const BuyProduct = async({params}: BuyProductProps) => {
  const product = await prisma.product.findUnique({where: {id: params.id}})
  const {getUser, isAuthenticated} = getKindeServerSession()

  const user = await getUser()

  if(user == null) {
    redirect("/")
  }

  if(product == null) {
    return <div>Product not found.</div>
  }

  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: product?.price!,
    currency: "inr",
    metadata: {productId: product?.id, userId: user?.id}
  })

  if(paymentIntent.client_secret == null) {
    throw Error("Stripe failed to create payment link.")
  }
  return (
    <CheckoutForm product={product as Product} clientSecret={paymentIntent.client_secret} />
  )
}
export default BuyProduct

//checkout form

"use client";

const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY as string
);

const CheckoutForm = ({ product, clientSecret }: CheckoutFormProps) => {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);

  return (
    <div className="pb-16 lg:p-2">
      <h1 className="font-bold text-red-500 text-center tracking-wide">This is in experimentation. May not work as intended.</h1>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-2 gap-6">
        <div className="flex flex-col px-2 pt-20 h-full items-center justify-center">
          <div className="relative h-[200px] w-full">
            <Image
              alt={product?.name}
              src={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL}/storage/v1/object/public/Zephyr-products/${product?.image}`}
              fill
              className="object-contain"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="my-8">
            <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold">{`${product?.name} (x${quantity})`}</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
            <Button
              disabled={quantity === 1}
              onClick={() => setQuantity((prev) => prev - 1)}
              variant="ghost"
              className="border border-border bg-accent hover:opacity-75 duration-100 transition-opacity ease-in-out"
            >
              -
            </Button>
            <div className="text-bold text-red-500 text-md">{quantity}</div>
            <Button
              disabled={quantity === 10}
              onClick={() => setQuantity((prev) => prev + 1)}
              variant="ghost"
              className="border border-border bg-accent hover:opacity-75 duration-100 transition-opacity ease-in-out"
            >
              +
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex px-4 pt-20 h-full items-center justify-center">
          <Elements
            options={{ clientSecret, appearance: { theme: "night" } }}
            stripe={stripePromise}
          >
            <Form price={product?.price} quantity={quantity} />
          </Elements>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

function Form({ price, quantity }: { price: number; quantity: number }) {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [errors, setError] = useState<string>();

  const finalPrice = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-IN").format(price * quantity);

  function handleSubmit(e: FormEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (stripe == null || elements == null) return;
    setLoading(true);

    stripe
      .confirmPayment({
        elements,
        confirmParams: {
          return_url: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYMENT_REDIRECT_URL}/stripe/purchase-success`,
        },
      })
      .then(({ error }) => {
        if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
          setError(error.message);
        } else {
          console.log(error);
          setError("An unexpected error occurred.");
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="w-full">
      //styling
    </form>
  );
}
export default CheckoutForm;

//webhook

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY as string)
export async function POST(req: NextRequest ) {
  const payload = await req.text()
  const response = JSON.parse(payload)
  const sig = req.headers.get("Stripe-Signature")

  const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
    payload,
    sig!,
    process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET!
  );
  
  if(event.type === "charge.succeeded") {
    const charge = event.data.object

    const productId = charge.metadata.productId
    const userId = charge.metadata.userId
    const email = charge.billing_details.email
    const price = charge.amount

    const product = await prisma.product.findUnique({where: {id: productId}})

    if(product == null || email == null) {
      return new NextResponse("Bad Request", {status: 400})
    }

    await prisma.purchased.create({
      data: {
        id: product.id,
        kindeAuth: userId,
        pricePaid: price,
      }
    })
  }
}


